# undefined method `total_pages' for #<Tuto::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc3b2473d80>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I found couple of similar cases but nothing to fix my problem...

I am using the gem Kaminari to paginate my app.

Since I added it, researches are failing and retrun this error `undefined method total_pages' for #<Tuto::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc3b2473d80>`

I have a private method in my **tutos controller** to filter my *tutos*

```
 def filter_tutos
  return if params[:query].blank?
  @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:query][:keyword]).includes(:user, :category) if params[:query][:keyword].present?
  @tutos = Tuto.joins(:user).where('users.nickname LIKE ?', params[:query][:user]) if params[:query][:user].present?
  @tutos = Tuto.joins(:category).where('categories.name LIKE ?', params[:query][:category]) if params[:query][:category].present?
 end
```

**index** method in tutos controller :

```
  def index
    filter_tutos if params[:query].present?
    @tutos ||= Tuto.all.page params[:page]
  end
```

in my view I have:

```
  .pagination
      = paginate @tutos
```

I added `paginates_per 5` in tuto model

Comment: total_pages is an attribute of a Tuto object but the method is called on an ARel instead of Tuto object. try converting @tutos in the index method to an  array of objects - `@tutos = (@tutos || Tuto.all.page params[:page]).to_a`

Comment: tried this too before your Answer but it wasn't good ;) but thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Pagination is not called on `@tutos`. If it is blank then all Tuto objects are paginated but not otherwise.

```
  def index
    filter_tutos if params[:query].present?
    @tutos = @tutos.count > 0 ? @tutos : Tuto.all
    @tutos = @tutos.page params[:page]
  end
```

Comment: It helps :) 
I added @tutos = Tuto.all 
I will make sure if works and upvote your answer thanks